# What are the most important Windows .dll files?

Tags: windows, boot, dll

What are the most important .dll files Windows use?

I'm making a Uplink like hacking game and one of the feature I'm working on would allow you to "destroy" a machine by deleting key Windows files.

The problem is, I'm not quite sure what those files are.

So far all i have is Kernel32.dll.
What else could i add?

Thanks.

Comment: get a VM, and start deleting things. That said, windows shouldn't let you delete anything critical, so anything it DOSEN"T let you delete should be alright

Comment: All system files are located in the `Windows` directory. I cannot provide specific details on how to actually destroy a Windows installation on moral grounds.

Comment: Alright but i don't wanna know how to delete those files, i just want their names.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not quite. Files in use cannot be deleted, yes, but anyone with administrator permissions can take ownership and delete files that are not currently in use but are critical to booting - thus rendering the system unbootable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go for:
Ntdll.dll,
ntoskrnl.exe,
user32.dll,
system32.dll,
hal.dll

and you can of course just delete key executable files in system32...

gl,
Refael